# How many transition elements are there?

Tags: transition-metals, terminology, periodic-table

I searched the internet and most of sites say there are 38 transition metals. But our textbook says that group 12 or the group of zinc *can not* be counted as transition metals, which already puts the number to 37.

Moreover, Sc, La and Ac also can't be counted as transition metals. That puts the number to 34. Y being in the same group as Sc should also be cancelled as transition metals making the number 33.

These are all my thoughts and haven't been varied by any reliable sources. And also it's based on our textbook. I would like to know what is wrong with these thoughts.

*Note*: The book considers thorium a d block element. Thus, according to the book the number of d block elements is 41.

Comment: In my point of view, the transition elements are all those belonging to the "small columns" of the table, whatever their chemical properties. So, they contain atoms from Sc to Zn, and the same in the next lines.

Comment: AFAIK, whole group 12 doesn't fit criteria for belonging to transition elements. Why isn't Sc or Y transition element?

Comment: According to definition ... To become transition element an elements STABLE ION must have unpaired electron in d orbital. The stable ion of Sc is 3+. In this ion there is no electron in d orbital. For this reason, Sc and Y is not transition element. This is the theory given in our book.

Comment: Related:  https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/119066/is-scandium-considered-a-transition-metal?r=SearchResults.  Note that the emergence of organometallic chemistry enters into the reckoning, as demonstrated with scandium.

Comment: "The book considers thorium a d block element." That depends on your point of view. See [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/136833/17175) for a discussion of what happens in the metal versus gaseous atoms.

Answer (score 6):

Shakespeare apparently said "What’s in a name? That which we call a rose, by any other word would smell as sweet." Rule no. 1, don't trust the internet until and unless you have some idea about the credentials of the website (and this comes with experience).

The usage of the term *transition metal* is nothing but historical. You can stick to IUPACs definition (https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/T06456)

> An element whose atom has an incomplete d sub-shell, or which can give rise to cations with an incomplete d sub-shell.

By that zinc should not be a transition element. The definition has nothing to do with paired electrons as you wrote in the comments.

Look at the history of word, this is from 18th century from the unabridged OED.

> transition element  n. Chemistry  [after Russian perexodnyj èlement (see transitional element n. at transitional adj. and n. Compounds)] (originally, now historical) any of the nine metallic elements forming group VIII of Mendeleev's periodic table; (now) any of a large class of metallic elements occupying the central block of the periodic table (groups IV b–VIII, I b, and II b, or 4–12, the d-block), which are characterized by partly filled d orbitals, commonly show variable valency and an ability to form coordination compounds, and form many coloured compounds; often extended to include also those elements having partly filled f orbitals (the lanthanides and actinides).

Comment: Doesn't all group 12 elements (not just Zn) fail to satisfy the definition of transition elements?

Comment: Right, as per IUPAC, Group 12 is not a transition metal group.

Answer (score 5):

First and foremost, *d-block elements* and *transition elements* are two different entities.
These terms become not exchangeable as you start using current [IUPAC definition of transition element](https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/T06456) (see [M. Farooq's answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/125781)).
Older textbooks included entire d-block, including Group 12 elements, into transition elements cohort because historically the name "transition" referred to the generic *chemical properties* ranging in-between those of elements from s- and p-blocks, at the same time ignoring lanthanoids and actinoids.

I think I found quite a strict yet simple definition that is also aligned with the IUPAC's one, and allowing to actually *count* the transition elements [1, p. 1357]:

> **transition element**.
> (transition metal).
> Any of a number of elements in which the filling of the outermost shell to eight electrons within a period is interrupted to bring the penultimate shell from 8 to 18 or 32 electrons.
> Only these elements can use penultimate shell orbitals as well as outermost shell orbitals in bonding.
> All other elements, called “major group” elements, can use only outermost shell orbitals in bonding.
> Transition elements include elements 21 through 29 (scandium through copper), 39 through 47 (ytterbium through silver), 57 through 79 (lanthanum through gold), and all known elements from 89 (actinium) on.
> All are metals.
> Many are noted for exhibiting a variety of oxidation states and forming numerous complex ions, as well as possessing extremely valuable properties
> in the metallic state.

Following this definition, there are nine transition elements in 3d-series, nine in 4d-series, 23 in 5d-series (including lanthanoids, the inner transition elements) and [currently] 30 in 6d-series (provided there are 118 elements and [oganesson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oganesson) is the heaviest known element), totaling *71 transition elements* (2021):

[image: Simple periodic table of elements with highlighted transition elements]
<sup>Adapted from [Periodic table, not highlighted.svg by Crossover1370](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Periodic_table,_not_highlighted.svg)</sup>

Strictly speaking, there is little known about electron configuration for elements with $Z > 108,$ so calling out an exact number of transition elements is likely going to be considered a bold move for the foreseeable future.

#### Reference

1. *Hawley’s Condensed Chemical Dictionary*, 16th ed.; Larrañaga, M. D., Lewis, R. J., Lewis, R. A., Hawley, G. G., Eds.; John Wiley & Sons, Inc: Hoboken, New Jersey, **2016**. ISBN 978-1-118-13515-0.

Comment: "Strictly speaking, there is little known about electron configuration for elements with  Z>108..." - What can we say about Cn (since it belongs to the group 12)? Its atomic number (Z = 112) is greater than 89 (actinium) which indicates that it is a transition metal, but also greater than 108. So, is there an uncertainty regarding it (probably the reason why textbooks don't mention if Cn is a transition metal or not)?

Comment: @Pal [Predicted electron configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copernicium#Predicted_properties) suggests that Cn is a transition element that follows the aforementioned trend, and to prove it otherwise one would need to use [experimental methods](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31473), which is pretty much impossible at the moment considering how unstable the element is.

Comment: @andselisk If we restrict ourselves to periods 4 to 6, is it okay to refer to elements in column 12 as post-transition elements instead? Or to be even more specific, d-block post-transition metals?

Answer (score 1):

The term "transition" has a geometric origin. The periodic table contains big and small columns, The big columns are number $1$, $2, 13, 14$, etc. The small columns are number $3$ to $12$, and they are all situated in the "transition" zone between the big columns $2$ and $13$. So $\ce{Zn}$ and the other elements of the column $12$ are called transition elements.