# Is Copernicium a transition metal?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, periodic-trends

Zinc, cadmium, mercury and copernicium belong to the group 12 of the periodic table. In my textbook , it is mentioned that zinc, cadmium and mercury are d-block elements, but not transition metals. But there is nothing mentioned about copernicium regarding this. This makes me wonder if there is a specific reason why Cn has been left out.

So, is Cn a transition metal? Also, if it is, could anyone please explain why is it so?

Comment: Copernicium may be newer than the textbook. So the textbook didn't know about it.

Comment: [Classified as a transition metal, Copernicium is a expected to be a solid at room temperature.](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/element/Copernicium)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many transition elements are there?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/125772/how-many-transition-elements-are-there)