# How is the electronic configuration of elements determined practically?

Tags: electronic-configuration, transition-metals

How is the electronic configuration of elements determined in practical? Theoretically, we use certain **rules** (Aufbau principle, Pauli exclusion principle, and Hund's rule) to define the electronic configuration of elements. There are some exceptional cases and some explanations for them. This is what I know about electronic configurations so far.

I wonder how we know the electronic structure of any element practically and how the exceptional configurations became known to us? I mean the electronic configuration of **copper**, according to rules, should be [Ar] 3d⁹ 4s² but in actual it is [Ar] 3d¹⁰ 4s¹. How did we determine this?

Similarly, how do we know that the electronic configuration of **tungsten** is [Xe] 6s² 4f¹⁴ 5d⁴? It could have been 6s¹ 5d⁵ (there is possibility). I'm not looking for the reasons for these exceptional configurations but a detailed explanation of the practical methods to determine the electronic structure of elements.

Comment: See https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31473/how-are-electronic-configurations-determined-experimentally#:~:text=There%20are%20lots%20of%20techniques,EELS%20spectroscopy%2C%20ELNES%20and%20EXELFS. for example